# JSF dataTable as CSS table with clickable rows?

Tags: html, jsf, css

Related questions have been asked but as there is not as yet any solid/acceptable answer, I thought I would re-phrase and clarify:

Is there a way within JSF to populate a `dataTable` or related query-result component without re-writing renderers as a W3C CSS table? This must enable clickable rows and row (versus column) styling a:hover, etc.

Example of desired rendered JSF component HTML from a query:

```
<div class="table">
    <a href="#" class="row">
        <span class="cell">Column-1-Value</span>
        <span class="cell">Column-2-Value</span>
    </a>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: You can do it manually using `<ui:repeat>` to render each row.

Comment: Thanks - could you clarify? Using `datatable` or using `<c:forEach>`?

Comment: You know that `<h:dataTable>` will generate a `<table>` HTML component. So, if you want to avoid this and display your data using `<div>`, you can use `<ui:repeat>` to iterate through your `List<Data>` elements and build your table using plain HTML elements. As a sample: `<div class="table>"<ui:repeat value="#{bean.lstData}" value="data"><a href="#" class="row"><span class="cell">#{data.Value1}</span><span class="cell">#{data.Value2}</span></a></ui:repeat></div>`

Comment: Perfect ... you guys were too fast - I was about to answer my own question as I just this working. The delay was that (one of the things I love about JSF) is that JSF was not rendering with zero error-messages. Reason? I was using the "items" attribute (from dataTable) versus "value". JSF simply ignores it completely even though it should have complained that the "value" was missing and that the "items" attribute is not part of the `<ui:repeat>` schema.

Comment: The `<h:dataTable>` doesn't have an `items` attribute at all. The `<c:forEach>` has.

Comment: Right - figured that out but one of the things that kills me about JSF is that it does not complain about it. It violates the schema to have such an attribute (and missing `values`) but instead it just does nothing. Hurts the JSF learning-curve.

Comment: I don't think I understand this site very well... was it a bad question to be down-voted? I scoured related questions and never saw anything that was the same/similar and thought I had asked the question properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the input provided, this is the complete answer (versus just in comments) tested in a Java EE/JSF container:

```
<div class="table">
  <ui:repeat value="#{BackingBean.list}" var="item">
    <h:outputLink value="url">
      <f:param name="ID" value="#{item.ID}"/>
      <span class="cell">#{item.ID}</span>
      <span class="cell">#{item.Name}</span>
    </h:outputLink>
  </ui:repeat>
</div>
```

The above can then be styled using CSS/3 `display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell`; respectively. Row is clickable and can be styled as desired.